# Running a Java Applet from Firefox with 1.6.0_17?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, plugins, java-applet

Anyone able to successfully run a Java Applet with the 1.6 Applet Plugin in Firefox?

I'm using an applet loaded in tomcat that other non-Mac users can access and run using their java applet plugin, but mine causes Firefox to hang and then crash.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do ALL java applets cause a crash? Or only this particular one? If it's just this particular one, then most likely it's a bug in that java applet itself. It's not very hard to crash a browser using Java, plugins aren't very well isolated in Firefox (unlike Chrome or Internet Explorer), and Java is easier to crash than Flash is.

Comment: The applet works when accessed from Windows machines running Firefox.

Comment: That is not what I asked. Can you run any OTHER java applets? If it's just that one applet, then logic says there's a bug in that applet. Just because it works on windows, doesn't 100% guarantee it wont crash somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you are looking for: [Java for OS X 2013-002: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559).

I followed only the first 3 out of 4 steps (as I don't need Web Start functionality) and restarted Firefox... voilà! Java applets work now.